# ffmpeg overlay one video on another and only keep sound of overlay video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

with code below I can overlay two video
`ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i ppt.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=700:-1 [overlay]; [1][overlay]  overlay=main_w - overlay_w:main_h - overlay_h " -map 1:a -c:a copy output.mp4`
However I only want too keep the audio of file.mp4(overlay video) what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map the first input's audio instead.

`ffmpeg -i file.mp4 -i ppt.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=700:-1 [overlay]; [1][overlay]  overlay=main_w - overlay_w:main_h - overlay_h " -map 0:a -c:a copy output.mp4`